# Run Function Every Minute In Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, twitter, autosave, minute

I am wondering if there is some way to run a function every minute in Cocoa.  I, personally, will be using this for saving content as the user types it in case they quit - But I have seen this effect also used in Twitter clients.  When the user keeps the window open, it will auto-update every x minutes without input from the user.  It seems as if this is common, and the language allows it, I just can't seem to find documentation on it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I, personally, will be using this for saving content as the user types it in case they quit - But I have seen this effect also used in Twitter clients.

A better solution would be to be the text view's delegate, and respond to `textDidChange:` by creating the *non-repeating* timer (if you have not done so already or it has already fired) and setting its fire date to X seconds in the future. Then, the user loses no more than X seconds' worth of work, not up to one minute, and the timer is not firing when the user has not typed anything.

Comment: Hey Peter:

I will definitely look into this.

Comment: Peter: This seems to work very well, but it causes my application window to lag a lot when inputting text.  I believe this is because it is saving the file to disk every time the function runs.  I didn't implement the timer on this function, as I didn't quite know how to make it not create a new timer on each of the function's run.  I imagine this would solve my problem, but I am not quite sure how to accomplish this.  Any ideas?

Comment: When the timer fires, release it (if you retained it earlier) and set the variable holding it to `nil`. Then you can test in `textDidChange:` whether the timer exists or not. Also, don't call the function (or send the message) directly from `textDidChange:`; just create the timer, and let it send the message when it fires.

Comment: Remember, the idea is for the timer to fire X seconds *after* the user's last change. That's why your `textDidChange:` method should postpone the timer with every change.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [NSTimer docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). It does exactly what you want.  You create an NSTimer that will repeat for as long as you want, and call a specific function with specified arguments.

Comment: Hey Dan:

So that's what NSTimer is for.  I have looked into that class before, but didn't quite know that you could use it for functions.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: NSTimer can't call a function directly; it can only send a message to an object. Your response to that message can be whatever you want, including calling a function. That said, I can't think of a reason why you would make this a function; you'd more likely just do the auto-save in the method.

Answer (score 2):

> I, personally, will be using this for
>   saving content as the user types it in
>   case they quit

Then you want [autosaving](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Articles/Autosaving.html), which takes care of that for you.

Comment: @Graham Lee

Would this work even though my NSTextFields were dynamically added to the screen?

Comment: If the text they represent is part of the document model, then yes.